# Trying to change Status Override on memberships but the record never completes

Tags: civimember, status

I am trying to change membership from Permanent Override to No or Override on a Specific Date, but the change isn't accepted. I have Admin access. Is there a background setting that might be impacting this?

Comment: what status is the person currently on

Comment: if you are using the overlay/pop-up style page, try instead to right click on the link you are using (Edit Membership?) and open as a new tab. then when it fails (if that is what it is doing) it may give you some more helpful error messages which you can paste here

Comment: and welcome :-)

Answer (score 2):

I've had a possibly related experience, where the status wasn't being updated automatically, and it seemed to be related to whether it's been overridden in the past. I noticed this related-sounding issue;

https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2974

and tried a more recent civicrm version and that fixed some aspects (the system job didn't update the status, but just editing the membership record fixed the status).

Comment: As the author of that issue, I'd say this is almost certainly the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for the original issue and this confirmation!